# Chart.js How to align two X-axis in bar chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I try to build a simple bar chart using chart.js with 2 x-axis: One on top and other on bottom.

The problem is two axis label and grid is not align. The top x-axis is align center and bottom x-axis is align left.

Please help me to make two x-axis align center. Thanks!

Fiddle:
`jsfiddle.net/gtmvkq4n/2/`

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking after the **offset** option

Example with multiple datasets:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'somelabel',
      xAxisID:'bar-x-axis1',
      data: [40, 50, 30, 12, 52]
    },
    {
      // ... other dataset...
    }]
  },
  options:{
    scales:{
      xAxes:[
        {
          id:'bar-x-axis1',
          type:'category',
          offset: true // <== that one!
        },
        {
          // ... other X axis...
        }]
    }
  }
});
```

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/

Comment: This answer is not marked as solution, but in my case it solved a problem

Answer (score 0):

Make your bar graph contains proper `groupSpace, barSpace, barWidth`

> (groupSpace * barSpace) * n + groupSpace = 1

Make this equation is correct, given n is the number of bars

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But can you explain more detail about your answer? I can't find `groupSpace, barSpace, barWidth` in any chart.js document.